# I keep getting bad substitution error on bash scripts with arrays

Tags: bash, scripts

I've been working on a Bash script using an array. I keep getting this message, "Bad substitution". So I Googled the problem and every example I came up with supposedly works but not on my computer. Here's a simple script that supposedly works.

```
#!/bin/bash
o="12345"
a=o
b=${!a}
echo ${a}
echo ${b}
```

But when I run it, I get this...

```
bob@Bobz-DT:~/IStests/test script$ sh test4.sh
test4.sh: 4: test4.sh: Bad substitution
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and the Bash version is...
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Can someone please tell me what's going on???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to run the script as `bash` and not `sh`.

So, run it with

```
bash test.sh
```

The other way, you could set the `execute` bit on your file by doing

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

then just run your script as

```
./test.sh
```

because you already have your command shell interpreter ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) as your first line `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thank you for getting back with this. And, of course, it works. I didn't know about running a script with "bash" instead of "sh".

Comment: @user314397  it's all good.  Sometimes at my job we say that the script always works when the other tech looks at it with you.  :)  Glad you got it working!